# double cover over $\mathbb{P}^2$ ramified on conics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I am reading the book [Compact Complex Surfaces](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-57739-0). At Section V.22, it states that the double covering $X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^2$ branched over a smooth conic is a quadric surface.

I am able to compute the Hodge numbers: $h^{0,0}(S)=h^{2,2}(S)=1,h^{1,1}(S)=2$ and others are zero.

By the classification of surfaces, it should be a Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{F}_n$ for some $n\geq0$.

How can I identify the $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just note that if $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is the equation of a smooth conic, then the double covering is given by the equation
$$
x_0^2 = f(x_1,x_2,x_3),
$$
where $x_0$ is an extra variable. Obviously, this is a smooth quadric.

Comment: I get it. Let me expend a bit for the answer: consider the projective bundle $\pi:L= \text{Tot}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1))\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^2$, this double cover is the zero locus of $V_+(t^2-\pi^*s)\subset L$ for a section $s\in H^0(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{O}(2)) $. We know that $L=\mathbb{P}^3-\{x\}$, so the double cover is given precisely by the equation $t^2=s(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.